Charts intervals on all PERPS revert back to 15min. No matter what
I'm getting this bug while trading today and its really limiting activity today. I will select the 1 minute interval on the PERP market charts, and as soon as i do, the interval reverts back to 15min every time. no what what you select.
Is anyone else having this issue?
its happening in my browser on my computer, and is also happening on my cell phone, connecting to Jupiter swap inside of the my wallet app browser.
Any Tips?
